# attaching a loading icon to a Table TD for an ajax call gets mixed up when multipule are running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a click event in a table to get more data (drill down report)  I am trying to show a loading icon on the row until the data is retrieved.  When I click on a second row before the first completed, it only removes the second loading icon. The first icon will stay there till I click it twice.

click event

```
self.t01_click = function (e, event) {

        trig = $(event.currentTarget);
        console.log(trig);
        if (trig.is('.expanded')) {
            e.details.removeAll();
            trig.removeClass('expanded');
        } else {
            trig.addClass('cellLoading');
            xhr_get(publish + "odata/pp_Result?id=uid&$filter=GroupingLevel eq '02_Programs' and OfferedGrp eq '"+e.OfferedGrp+"' ").done(function (allData) {
                e.details([]);
                var mappedLogs = $.map(allData.d.results, function (item) { return new rpt(item) });
                e.details(mappedLogs);

                trig.addClass('expanded');
                trig.removeClass('cellLoading');

            }).fail(function (data) {
                console.log('fail');
                trig.removeClass('cellLoading');
            });


        }
    }
```

ajax function

```
function xhr_get(url, datap) {
        //  console.log(url);
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: datap,
            async:true,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you declare `trig` locally? Or is there a reason for it to be a global variable?

If you declare it locally, each callback will reference the correct instance of `trig`:

```
self.t01_click = function (e, event) {

    //Declare trig locally:
    var trig = $(event.currentTarget);
    console.log(trig);
    if (trig.is('.expanded')) {
        e.details.removeAll();
        trig.removeClass('expanded');
    } else {
        trig.addClass('cellLoading');
        xhr_get(publish + "odata/pp_Result?id=uid&$filter=GroupingLevel eq '02_Programs' and OfferedGrp eq '"+e.OfferedGrp+"' ").done(function (allData) {
            e.details([]);
            var mappedLogs = $.map(allData.d.results, function (item) { return new rpt(item) });
            e.details(mappedLogs);

            trig.addClass('expanded');
            trig.removeClass('cellLoading');

        }).fail(function (data) {
            console.log('fail');
            trig.removeClass('cellLoading');
        });


    }
}
```

Here's a demonstration of this idea:

```js
$("button").click( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $span = $this.prev();
    
    $span.text("...loading...");
    $span.attr("class","loading");
    $this.hide();
    
    window.setTimeout( function() {
        $span.attr("class","loaded");
        $span.text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...");
    }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.nodata {
    color: silver;
}

.loading {
    color: red;
}

.loaded {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="nodata">...</span><button>Load Data</button><br />
<span class="nodata">...</span><button>Load Data</button><br />
<span class="nodata">...</span><button>Load Data</button><br />
<span class="nodata">...</span><button>Load Data</button><br />
<span class="nodata">...</span><button>Load Data</button><br />
<span class="nodata">...</span><button>Load Data</button><br />
<span class="nodata">...</span><button>Load Data</button><br />
<span class="nodata">...</span><button>Load Data</button><br />
```

The variable `$span` is declared within the `onclick` function. When the function is executed, that instance of `$span` is available to the `window.setTimeout` callback function.

Comment: WOW I totally missed that it wasn't being declared locally.  thanks!